# accept_nested_attributes_for in Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has accept_nested_attributes_for already works with Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.9.1????

I keep getting this error

```
undefined method accept_nested_attributes_for' for #<Class:0x00000108da2140>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

owh yeah should be accepts_nested_attributes_for (with 's')

Someone should clean up those Google searches!